# Redux initial state causes undefined error

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am following an udemy course to learn redux coding on codePen, however, I got this following error.

```
redux.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at policies (pen.js:61)
at redux.min.js:1
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at redux.min.js:1
at e.combineReducers (redux.min.js:1)
at pen.js:73
```

it tells me that it is because the name from the policies reducer function could not read the action.payload.name because it's undefined. I did not see the instructor have the same problem, but I have faithfully checked my code and it's identical to his. I just can't understand how I can fix it to display the state correctly.

I have debugged and tried to fix the problem, but so far the code keeps throwing error unless I delete the action.payload.name from the policies reducer function.

```js
console.clear();
// people dropping off a form (Aaction Creator)

const createPolicy =(name, amount)=>{
  // console.log(name,amount,'test createpolicy')
  return { // Action (a form in our analogy)
    
    type:'CREATE_POLICY',
    payload: {
      name:name,
      amount: amount
    }
  };
};

const deletePolicy = (name) =>{
  return {
    type:'DELETE_POLICY',
    payload:{
      name: name     
    }
  }
}

const createClaim = (name, amountOfMoneyToCollect) =>{
  return {
    type:'CREATE_CLAIM',
    payload:{
      name: name,
      amountOfMoneyToCollect: amountOfMoneyToCollect
    }
  };
};


// Reducers (Departments!)
// default oldListOfClaims=[] is for initial state. 
const claimsHistory=(oldListOfClaims=[], action)=>{
  if(action.type==="CREATE_CLAIM"){
    // we care about this action (FORM!)
    return [...oldListOfClaims, action.payload];
  }
  // we don't care the action (FORM!)
  return oldListOfClaims;
};

const accounting=(bagOfMoney=100, action)=>{
  if(action.type==='CREATE_CLAIM'){
    return bagOfMoney - action.amountOfMoneyToCollect;
  }
  else if(action.type==='CREATE_POLICY'){
    return bagOfMoney + action.payload.amount;
  }
  return bagOfMoney;
}

const policies = ( listOfPolicies = [], action)=>{
  if(action.type = 'CREATE_POLICY'){
      console.log( action.payload,'test playload name')
    return [...listOfPolicies,action.payload.name]
  }
  else if(action.type='DELETE_POLICY'){

     return listOfPolicies.filter(name =>
        name!==action.payload.name);
  }
  return listOfPolicies;
};

const { createStore, combineReducers} = Redux;

const ourDepartments = combineReducers ({
  accounting: accounting,
  claimsHistory: claimsHistory,
  policies: policies
})

const store = createStore(ourDepartments);

console.log(store)


store.dispatch(createPolicy('Alex', 20));
store.dispatch(createPolicy('Jim', 30));
store.dispatch(createPolicy('Bob', 40));
console.log(store.getState());
```

I would expect to see the console.log of the current state after the new names and amounts are dispatched to the store. and figure out why this error keeps occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review your `policies` reducer - you are assigning rather than comparing against action types when checking against your types. Update it to the code below:

```
const policies = ( listOfPolicies = [], action)=>{
  // previously if(action.type = 'CREATE_POLICY'){
  if(action.type === 'CREATE_POLICY'){
      console.log( action.payload,'test playload name')
    return [...listOfPolicies,action.payload.name]
  }
  // previously else if(action.type='DELETE_POLICY'){
  else if(action.type==='DELETE_POLICY'){

     return listOfPolicies.filter(name =>
        name!==action.payload.name);
  }
  return listOfPolicies;
};
```